# “Darkroom” mode screen filter (like in f.lux)

Tags: windows-7, display

I recently installed [f.lux](https://justgetflux.com/) at my Windows machine and discovered this awesome [feature](https://justgetflux.com/news/pages/bigupdate/):

> A new “darkroom” mode, which inverts colors and gets very red

I’ve been looking for software like this without any luck. Does it even exist or is this a very unique feature only used in f.lux so far?

[image]

Comment: Can you maybe upload sample before/after images so that we get a better idea? IIRC you don't have enough reputation yet to insert images, but just put them on some image hosting site and [edit] the links into your post. Someone will come along and actually include them.

Comment: We will need much more information to give good recommendations here – asking for "a tool like X" is never giving enough details, even if linked. You should always list your requirements explicitly. Please see [How to ask for an alternative to some software](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) and the questions linked to it for details. Currently it's even unclear if you're looking for an image editor, screen filter, or screen saver.

Comment: @jordy19 Are you saying that you found software that does this (f.lux), but you want other software that does this?  If so, why?

Comment: The darkroom mode in F.lux only allows you to use a red filter, I was wondering if there is software around that allows you to use different colored filters.

Comment: Have you tried adjusting the colour temperature in f.lux?